# Run "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate" in code; Hibernate schema validation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

usually I would set

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

in the persistence.xml if I would like to check if my database is consistent with my annotated entities (Am I right?)

Now this validation would fail at application start up because there will be some migrations after, so I have to disable validation at this place.
But after my migrations I would like to run anything out of my code which compares that my database tables meet the annotated entities of my code!

Answer (score 0):

The Validation looks for perfection you dont need. In example, the Range of `java.sql.Date` may differs from the range of the congrete Column type Date.

Anyway, try this after your startup and migrations:

```
 AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration();
 conf.addClass(...);
 conf.validateSchema(...);
```